# Is it possible to prevent VS2010 killing the WebDev.WebServer process?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, webdev.webserver

Since I've starting using VS 2010 I've noticed that whne I stop the debugger it also kills the development web server. In VS 2008 I would regularly work without the debugger attached. Is it possible to do this in 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible if you start Visual Studio with <kbd>F5</kbd>.  It considers the web server the debugee process and will kill it at the end of the debugging session.

You can however start the process without debugging and continue to work with the web server for an extended period of time via: <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just do not use the development web server ;)